# Bring User Application to Topmost Overlapping the Windows TaskBar

Tags: vb.net, winforms, screen-resolution, taskbar

I am working with a Windows form application, it has fixed dimensions **1024,768**, And I have Windows Resolution **1366,768**.
My requirement is to automatically send back to ***Windows TaskBar***.
Below I am attaching the screen shot of the currently working system.

I have gone through various solution given on the internet and most of them saying for full screen , but there is a requirement to set resolution which I mentioned above.

[image: TaskBar Suppressing Program Space]
Anybody suggest me?

Comment: If you show the form in normal size without maximizing it and set its `TopMost` to true, it will be shown over taskbar.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

If you open the properties (of your form) you need to look for topmost and set it to True.
Credit to:  Reza Aghaei

Comment: I did try in a test app.. But once it opens.. It remains on top of Taskbar but as soon. We press cntl+d or mouse click to another window. It never comes over Taskbar.

Comment: Do you mean when It doesn't have focus it won't work? Or does it totally stop working when you lose focus but once

Comment: Once only when it starts first time

Comment: That is obviously not normal behavior, when re focused it should work like when started. Won't be able to help you without some code concerning the form layout properties etc.